# Почему Phpstorm интерпретатор не видит локальный php?

Tags: php, phpstorm, linux-mint

На linux mint установлен и переустановлен уже не раз php. В папке /usr/bin/php А в Phpstorm не могу добавить локальный интерпретатор, он его просто не видит, даже если выбираю папку по пути, в папке bin просто нет php. А в проводнике оно есть. Вообще все что связано с php, через окно Phpstorm вообще не видно, как будто нет в папке, а они есть ))).

[image: скрин]

Comment: Вызов в консоли `php -v` даёт что-нибудь? Ставили пакет `php-cli`?

Comment: да, установлено, скрин приложил в описание

Answer (score 0):

Решено,
Установленный PHPSTORM из пакетного менеджера в Linux Mint 20 криво работает и не видит полностью файловую систему. Видимо при установке чтото с правами.
переустановил из консоли , все норм.